# Issue for Create trigger send for cloud portals

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

[image]Failed to start the selected triggered send(s): A problem occurred Starting the following Triggered Sends. Please contact Customer Service for additional information.Name : NewTestDemo\
External Key : NewTestDemo \
Message :\
The email ID=355, contained 4 validation errors. Refer to the Triggered Send Email Validation error log, ID = 790560228

Comment: Did you contact customer support ? This doesn't look like a problem that a community can help you with, the support team has more access to logs and tools to help you clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the toolbar Validate from Content -> Emails -> (your email).  This is most likely caused by missing required personalization strings -- like the physical mailing address, profile/preference center links, the unsubscribe link, etc.